# Getting custom HTTP request headers in web.py?

Tags: python, http-headers, web.py, custom-headers

I know that, with web.ctx.env, I can get [a lot of information](http://www.mail-archive.com/webpy@googlegroups.com/msg01133.html) that comes from the headers -- but only the standard headers. Is it possible to obtain all HTTP request headers from within a GET or POST method in web.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that it has only standard headers? Cos I'm using it to check `web.ctx.env.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'` which is not in the list on that page. I also get values of `HTTP_X_FILE_NAME` and `HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE` headers that I set in xhr like this: `xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-File-Type", file.type );`.